# external multithreading sort

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, sorting

I need to implement external multithreading sort. I dont't have experience in multithreading programming and now I'm not sure if my algorithm is good anoth also I don't know how to complete it. My idea is:

1. Thread reads next block of data from input file
2. Sort it using standart algorith(std::sort)
3. Writes it to another file
4. After this I have to merge such files. How should I do this?

   - If I wait untill input file will be entirely processed until merge
     I recieve a lot of temporary files
   - If I try to merge file straight after sort, I can not come up with
     an algorithm to avoid merging files with quite different sizes, which
     will lead to O(N^2) difficulty.

Also I suppose this is a very common task, however I cannot find good prepared algoritm in the enternet. I would be very grateful for such a link especially for it's c++ implementation.

Comment: Gnu sort does this. Multi-threading on the initial pass that sorts "chunks" of data that fit in memory, creating a temp file for each chunk. After the initial pass, the merge process (16-way merge by default) is performed in a single thread. This is a text file sort with a lot of options, so it's somewhat complex: [gnu sort.c](http://github.com/goj/coreutils/blob/rm-d/src/sort.c) .

Comment: Thanks. Don't you know why merge performed in a single thread?

Comment: Each merge step is reading 16 files and writing 1 file, so the process is I/O bound on the writes to the single file, and not CPU bound. The OS and drives buffer writes (write behind), so the writes are effectively overlapped with the merge process. The merge process only has to generate data that on average (due to buffering), is fast enough to keep the process I/O bound on the writes, so multi-threading is not needed for the merge steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer isn't that simple, and it actually depends on many factors, amongst them the number of items you wish to process, and the relative speed of your storage system and CPUs.

But the question is why to use multithreading at all here. Data too big to be held in memory? So many items that even a qsort algorithm can't sort fast enough? Take advantage of multiple processors or cores? Don't know.

I would suggest that you first write some test routines to measure the time needed to read and write the input file and the output files, as well as the CPU time needed for sorting. Please note that I/O is generally A LOT slower than CPU execution (actually they aren't even comparable), and I/O may not be efficient if you read data in parallel (there is one disk head which has to move in and out, so reads are in effect serialized - even if it's a digital drive it's still a device, with input and output channels). That is, the additional overhead of reading/writing temporary files may more than eliminate any benefit from multithreading. So I would say, first try making an algorithm that reads the whole file in memory, sorts it and writes it, and put in some time counters to check their relative speed. If I/O is some 30% of the total time (yes, that little!), it's definitely not worth, because with all that reading/merging/writing of temporary files, this will rise a lot more, so a solution processing the whole data at once would rather be preferable.

Concluding, don't see why use multithreading here, the only reason imo would be if data are actually delivered in blocks, but then again take into account my considerations above, about relative I/O-CPU speeds and the additional overhead of reading/writing the temporary files. And a hint, your file accessing must be very efficient, eg reading/writing in larger blocks using application buffers, not one by one (saves on system calls), otherwise this may have a detrimental effect if the file(s) are stored on a machine other than yours (eg a server).

Hope you find my suggestions useful.

Comment: For example comparison operation may be very expensive.